How to write Query with Predicate in SwiftUI detail view
I'm trying to write a @Query with a custom Predicate in a SwiftUI detail view. When I click items in the list the app hangs and memory usage increases linearly forever.
If I put the predicate on the @Query in the main view, the app works fine.
This is all based on the SwiftUI+SwiftData template app with extremely minimal modifications in the detail view:
Detail view (where issue occurs):
struct DetailView: View {
    var item: Item

    // Issue occurs when a Query with a filter is set. Without the filter it works fine
    // contents of Predicate doesn't matter so long as it's valid
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Item> { item in
        true
    }) private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
            Text("Count: \(items.count)")
        }
    }
}

List view:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    // If this Query is modified, no issue
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(item: item)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
}

Data model:
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

App runtime:
@main
struct TestSwiftDataApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


I’m not sure if there’s a performance disadvantage but you can always just add your own computed variable that takes all the unfiltered results and then just filter it manually yourself

navigation links are rendered before they are tapped

I think maybe the solution is just to take the query out of the detail view and Pass the item count as a constructor argument

@User45i6h45ih3455 this is a contrived example for simplicity

This is not a documented way of using NavigationSplitView. Can you use NavigationSplitView as described in the documentation? That is, your List should have a selection: and the split view should automatically show the detail view in the detail: view builder based on the selection. You should not use a destination-based NavigationLink.

Also, I cannot reproduce this on iOS 17.4. Everything works as expected - the app doesn't hang.

I have been able to reproduce this on macOS and I could see in the console with Core Data debugging logging active that the same fetch was executed over and over again when I clicked on an item in the sidebar. I can also verify that changing the implementation of the NavigationSplitView as suggested by @Sweeper fixes this issue.

I forgot to say that when reproducing the issue I was able to "fix" the issue the same way OP did, by removing the predicate.

Some more research, when using NavigationLink I see one fetch being performed in the console but  with the selection variant (without the NavigationLink) I see two fetches. When I add let _ = Self._printChanges() to the body of each view I see that the difference is because when selecting an item in the sidebar the change of the selection property also triggers a fetch being performed apart from the one in the DetailView. It looks like a bug to me but certainly something to be aware of for now if the query returns a lot of objects..

@Sweeper So in the project that inspired this, I was actually using NavigationStack instead of NavigationSplitView. Both for that project and the sample code here, it seems like switching to using navigationDestination has resolved the problems? If you want to write an answer suggesting that I will accept it

And yes, when I use Self._printChanges() it just says @self changed over and over again

Note that while it's true that fixed it, I do keep hitting this issue again with additional navigation links...frustrating

This is not a documented way of using NavigationSplitView. You should use a List selection to control when the detail view is shown.
@Query private var items: [Item]
@State private var selectedItem: PersistentIdentifier?

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        List(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item.id) {
                    Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                }
            }
        }
    } detail: {
        if let selectedItem, let item: Item = modelContext.registeredModel(for: selectedItem) {
            DetailView(item: item)
        } else {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

If you are using NavigationStack instead, using the value-based navigationDestination(for:) fixes the issue.
NavigationStack {
    List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            NavigationLink(value: item) {
                Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
        DetailView(item: item)
    }
}


NavigationStack solution has fixed my issue. Is there a reason you've chosen to retrieve it based on the ID instead of passing the item directly?

@Ezekiel In the NavigationSplitView version, the ForEach(item) uses the id property for the tags of the list rows, and List selection is based on that, so it is more natural this way. For NavigationStack, there is indeed no reason to do that - it's simply more convenient to copy-paste :)
